# Solr occupying less space after re-indexing

Tags: memory, solr

After modifying all my my documents(reindex), the core directory now occupies about three times less space`(~7GB to ~2GB)` on disc. What might be the reason?

No data was removed from records.

Comment: What have you done? Updated the solr version? Altered the schema.xml? If you altered the schema, would you post the before and after version?

Comment: In Solr schema each field have stored property you might have changed that property for one or more field from true to false.

Comment: did you delete / replaced some documents before the reindexing? If so, the explanation is that when you delete a document it is not physically purged from the index. The corresponding entry is only marked with the 'deleted' bit. The optimize or purgeDeletes=true will remove it physically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your index were not optimized and when you ran a full reindex solr optimized than making the index size much less than before.